# Merge [startup] ⇒ [boot]

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

***This post serves as a public record to notify users of changes on [Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/).***

```
updating post history, 5 rows affected
updating posts, 3 rows affected
updating PostTags associations, 1 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 0 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [boot] and [startup] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
Tag Synonym startup -> boot was approved!
Broadcasting tag-engine reload
```